# Sleep() vs _sleep() functions

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Currently, I am working on an old project developed (in C and C++) for Windows with Visual Studio 2010 or less. We would like to update it for newer version such as Visual Studio 2015 or 2017.

I have found that the `_sleep()` function is [no longer supported by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt620088.aspx) and that instead I shall use the [`Sleep()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) function.

I didn't find the equivalent [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) for the old `_sleep()` function and I wonder if both functions behave exactly identical ? This [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dbd2073d-d8ce-4a39-b7b7-29549969536f/what-is-sleep?forum=vcgeneral) makes me wondering if the only differences are in the types of the argument ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You might look at [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) if you want to modernize your code.

Comment: Exactly as the documentation states. Switching to `Sleep` should be a seamless transition from `_sleep`

Comment: Thanks for the `sleep_for` function. We also have the same question for C project (I will add the C tag as well).

Comment: if look for old crt code - in file `slbeep.c` - `void __cdecl _sleep(unsigned long dwDuration)
{

    if (dwDuration == 0) {
        dwDuration++;
    }
    Sleep(dwDuration);

}` - so `_sleep` is very thin shell over `Sleep`

Comment: sleep() is a posix function, once supported by Windows NT and Microsoft's C compiler.  It acquired a leading underscore after the posix subsystem fell out of use, too many short lowercase identifiers in the global namespace.  As long as you'd consider posix functions you might as well consider Windows functions :)

Comment: @HansPassant - Windows never supported POSIX fully. How do you explain sleep() accepting seconds and _sleep() milliseconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As RbMm mentioned, `_sleep` had been [implemented](http://www.cnhintl.com/it/DataMaster/1-VB6/VC98/CRT/SRC/SLBEEP.C) as a very thin wrapper around `Sleep`:

```
void __cdecl _sleep(unsigned long dwDuration)
{

    if (dwDuration == 0) {
        dwDuration++;
    }
    Sleep(dwDuration);

}
```

To confirm, we can test it. Fortunately it's easy to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    auto tm1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    _sleep(250);
    auto tm2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    Sleep(250);
    auto tm3 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "_sleep took " << (tm2-tm1)/1ms << " ms, Sleep took " << (tm3-tm2)/1ms << " ms\n";
}
```

Output:

```
_sleep took 250 ms, Sleep took 250 ms
```

So it appears both `_sleep` and `Sleep` sleep for the specific number of milliseconds.
`_sleep` is a MSVC CRT function, and `Sleep` is a Windows API.
So in MSVC they should be interchangeable.

One minor difference is that in case of a `0` argument, `_sleep` sleeps for `1ms` whereas `Sleep` doesn't sleep at all.

Comment: simply look for [`slbeep.c`](http://www.cnhintl.com/it/DataMaster/1-VB6/VC98/CRT/SRC/SLBEEP.C) - here `_sleep` implementation. not need any tests

Comment: I'd count that as an improvement. Why would you ever want to sleep for zero milliseconds.

Comment: @DavidA.Gray When you specify the amount of time to sleep, it's a minimum. The platform can put you to sleep for longer if that is beneficial to system performance. So a sleep for zero (or more) milliseconds says to the platform that now would be a good time to put you to sleep if it will help performance but if it won't help performance, you can continue to do useful work. It's commonly done at optimal pre-emption points such as right after releasing some locks (to give other threads a chance at it) or right before acquiring some (to reduce the odds you'll be pre-empted while holding it).

Comment: This was especially useful before there were multicore processors. `Sleep(0)` is an effective way to hand back your control of the CPU core to the OS.